# javascript not adding decimal point in maths calculation using values from select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I have a dropdown mean with various values...

```
<select id="number1a" onChange="Addition()">
  <option value="0" selected>-</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="7.5">7.5</option>
</select>

<select id="number1b" onChange="Addition()">
<option value="0" selected>-</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="5.5">5.5</option>
</select>
```

and a javascript function that adds the values and displays it it a div...

```
<script>
function Addition(){
number1a = parseInt(document.getElementById('number1a').value);
number1b = parseInt(document.getElementById('number1b').value);
output = number1a + number1b;
document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = +output;
</script>
```

and the div to display the maths...

```
<div id="score"></div>
```

The function works and display a number but it ignores the decimal, so if I select from the dropdown '10' and then '5' from the next dropdown, it display 15 in the , but if i select 10 and 5.5 it display 16 and not 15.5?

I have tried to add in `.toFixed(2);` but it has no effect, I get the same result. for example...

```
var output = outputnum.toFixed(5);
document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = +outputnum;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) gives you an Integer. You could use [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) instead to preserve decimals

Comment: `parseInt()` -> `parseFloat()`

Comment: You used `parseFloat` insted `parseInt`

Comment: excellent, `parseFloat` did the trick, its now displaying the decimals. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is in these lines:

```
number1a = parseInt(document.getElementById('number1a').value);
number1b = parseInt(document.getElementById('number1b').value);
```

The function `parseInt` always returns an Integer value ([as described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)). So instead of 5.5, it will return the nearest Integer, which is 6.

To get the actual value of 5.5, you will need to use the `parseFloat()` method, as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat). So just change these two lines to:

```
number1a = parseFloat(document.getElementById('number1a').value);
number1b = parseFloat(document.getElementById('number1b').value);
```

and it should work.